# Python - saving value over multiple calling of function

Tags: python, object, instance

I call a Python script multiple times and I want to save value of a dictionary, but it gets initialized every time when it is called. I've defined that variable in

```
def__init__(self):
    self.newdictt = dict()
```

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
        my_dict = {"camel": config_file, service: thisisjson_dict}

        self.newdictt.update(my_dict)

        with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(self.newdictt, json_file)
```

But self.newdictt gets overwrited every time

Comment: Do you want to save it across multiple invocations of the *script*, or multiple calls of the *function* within the same run?  For the latter, you can just append each dict to a list in memory.  If you want to remember the value after the script exits, you want to write it to disk.

Comment: Yes, I want to save it across multiple invocations of the script

Comment: @Irenaaa You need to read the file and parse it into a dict.

Comment: Is this the whole code? You only store the data but never actually retrieve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already saving the dict to a file. Before you create an empty dict, first check if the file exists and read it.